Clarification on MPPT circuit
I've looked into some MPPT circuits from Solar Inverters and there are some aspects that I would like to clarify.
I watched this YouTube video from EEVBlog where, in collaboration with an EEVBlog forum user Phoenix, has made an in-depth circuit diagram of the inverter. I've taken a ScreenShot of the video where the circuit diagram is shown:

However, by looking deeply at the MPPT circuit which he labeled as "PV BOOST INPUTS", there is something that doesn't seem right to me. Let me explain what I understand an MPPT circuit does since if this is wrong, it could render the question pointless and I would like correction if I'm wrong. So, in my view, an MPPT circuit is not exactly a Boost converter, it simply keeps a constant current flow from the panels since they are a DC source that has a Maximum Power Point. So the MPPT should draw current at a constant rate that gives the best $$V * I$$ result, the Maximum Power Point. This isn't exactly trivial since the Inverter provides not only a variable voltage output but also a variable power output. So I understand the capacitor bank is not exactly smoothing capacitors as we see in DC power supplies at the output, they actually store energy to ensure the inverter can draw current (and power) from the panels at a constant rate and output a variable power rate, therefore needing to store the energy for at most $$\frac{\frac{1}{frequency}}{2}$$ of the output signal. In this circuit diagram by EEVBlog, the MPPT is designed as a boost converter. In my view, this has a drawback: it only works if the PV array output voltage is lower than the maximum voltage that is necessary on the capacitor bank. If the PV array has a voltage higher than the voltage at the capacitor bank, there is no way to prevent current from flowing from the panels to the capacitor bank even if the MOSFET Q3 is OFF, since it is in parallel with the inductor and the capacitor bank, it is unable to prevent current from flowing.
I don't think EEVBlog would get the schematic wrong, especially since I looked at another solar inverter teardown available in this YouTube video and it shows exactly the same circuit schematic as EEVBlog, with the MOSFET (or IGBT) in parallel. Besides, in the same video, I can only see 1 Diode on the MPPT side of the Inverter.
Then I googled "MPPT circuit" and came across this circuit from 320volt.com:

This circuit does not seem to have the same problem, since it features 2 diodes and is not exactly a boost converter, which makes sense to me because in my view, the MPPT should not exactly boost the voltage, but instead keep a constant flow of current, whether increasing or decreasing the voltage, as necessary. This circuit features the MOSFET (or IGBT) in series with the inductor and the load, allowing switching off if the voltage from the panels is higher than the output voltage and features 2 diodes, one of them is placed similar to a buck converter. This circuit does not seem to have the problem of the other inverters.
I then looked at the Deye Solar Inverter Datasheet (the one from the EEVBlog teardown) and I found the "Max PV Input Voltage" is 500V, whereas the "MPPT Voltage Range" is 150-425V. Is this because my understanding that the inverter cannot control the current flow from the panels above the maximum voltage at the capacitor bank, since it is set up as a boost converter is correct? If yes, then why didn't they design the circuit like the third circuit I've quoted (or perhaps a different circuit), which would allow for a higher PV input voltage, thus allowing for more efficient overpaneling? Is it because a simple Boost Converter is cheaper than the third circuit I've attached, is it because it is more efficient, or is it because the third circuit is only adequate for off-grid battery charging?
Then I looked at the datasheet of the SOFAR inverter and the maximum "MPPT operating voltage range" is the same as the "Max. input voltage", which does not seem to confirm my suspicion of it only being able to get the Maximum Power from the panels when the PV voltage is low enough. Is this because the Datasheet is not correct and the manufacturer is adverstising something that is not true?


in my view, an MPPT circuit is not exactly a Boost converter

MPPT is not a type of DC-DC converter, rather it is a type of algorithm used to control a converter. The converter itself can be any type: buck, boost, buck-boost, and others... depending on circumstances like input/output voltage ranges etc. Sometimes there is no DC-DC converter and it is just PWM into a load. What makes it MPPT is the control algorithm.

So the MPPT should draw current at a constant rate that gives the best \$ V∗I \$
result, the Maximum Power Point.

Indeed.

the capacitor bank (...) actually store energy to ensure the inverter can draw current (and power) from the panels at a constant rate and output a variable power rate, therefore needing to store the energy

Correct. PV panels produce DC power, it varies with weather and passing clouds but over one mains frequency period it's pretty constant. On the AC side, if the inverter is single phase its output power is pulsed, so the caps are needed to store the energy to bridge the gap. They play the same role (in reverse) as the caps in an AC-DC switching power supply with power factor correction.
If the inverter is three phase, this is less of a problem: when it is balanced, voltage and current are AC but the sum of instantaneous power on three phases is constant. From the power point of view, three phase is DC that also works with transformers and induction motors.

If the PV array has a voltage higher than the voltage at the capacitor bank, there is no way to prevent current from flowing from the panels to the capacitor bank even if the MOSFET Q3 is OFF.

Correct. In fact, for the MPPT to actually do its job and track the maximum power point, it has to boost voltage. Otherwise it's just a diode. So voltage on the caps will always be higher than on the panels, unless the inverter decides to reduce its output power to a point where the MPPT is not needed.
This is not a problem, because the inverter will step down the DC bus voltage to the desired AC voltage, simply by using the adequate PWM duty cycles. The minimum value of the DC bus voltage is a bit above mains peak voltage, to avoid clipping the peaks of the sinewave. But the maximum value is only set by component ratings and safety margins. So, to output 230VAC, it will work fine with 350-500V on the DC bus caps, with maybe a little bit more losses on the high end.

Then I googled "MPPT circuit" and came across this circuit from 320volt.com:

This is a buck converter, it can only lower voltage. You'd use it to charge a low voltage battery from a much higher voltage panel. In this case boosting voltage will never be required, so you may as well use a simpler, cheaper and more efficient buck than a buck-boost.
It's a common arrangement because PV wires are long, thus higher voltage with lower current makes sense. For example 120V 10A panels, then a buck MPPT charge controller, and 12V 100A via short cables to the battery.

the "Max PV Input Voltage" is 500V, whereas the "MPPT Voltage Range" is 150-425V.

I guess they set the DC bus limit at 500V due to component ratings plus safety margin. As said before, in order to do its job, the MPPT has to boost. Perhaps  above 425V input the result would be exceeding the max 500V on the DC bus, so it can't boost, so it disables the MPPT.
It is normal to have a "MPPT range" lower than the "safe range".
PV panels also have a MPP voltage lower than the maximum output voltage.
The idea is, if the inverter isn't using all the power from PV, then PV voltage will rise. In this case, the panels can already produce more power than necessary: there is no need for the MPPT algo.

Is this because my understanding that the inverter cannot control the current flow from the panels above the maximum voltage at the capacitor bank, since it is set up as a boost converter is correct?

Yes

If yes, then why didn't they design the circuit like the third circuit I've quoted

Because your circuit is a buck: to get the ~330-350V needed to output 230VAC, you'd need PV voltage to be above that. So the inverter would only work with a large number of panels. It would be much less practical.
In the usual boost MPPT topology, the inverter circuit can already lower voltage from DC bus to AC. It makes no sense to duplicate this feature in the MPPT. Instead, a boost MPPT is a good complement: it allows a wide input voltage range.

Many thanks for your very detailed answer. There is still one last thing I would like to clarify. You say "it isn't a problem" for the MPPT to not be able to regulate the current if the PV voltage is higher than the DC bus voltage. But I still think it is a problem for a scenario where your would want to overpanel. (text too long, had to split)

Suppose you have a PV array with a voltage higher than the maximum MPPT max voltage range. It is true that for sunny days, an 450V array would be already producing more power than the inverter could handle so this wouldn't be a problem. But for cloudy days the voltage is the same and the power is much lower and this would be a problem because the inverter would not be able to get as much power from the panels as it would if it was not designed as a boost converter, right? Or am I missing something here? (Of course you could assume you consider cloudy days negligible but I don't see as 0 loss)

You can't use a 450V Voc array on the Deye. PV has a negative tempco on Voc (just like diodes, which they are). Voc is specified at 25°C. In winter, at very low temperatures, "450V Voc @25°C" will exceed 500V, possibly harming the inverter. So it's not really a problem. That said the 500V limit on the DEYE is still annoying, it's one of the reasons I picked Solis instead, it has 600V max input rating.

The 500V limit is even more annoying because these inverters really love overpaneling: the "official" 6kW limit on mine is only about the grid output power, but it will happily ingest 8.5kW from PV and split that between battery charging and grid output without clipping. I believe DEYE does the same. The topology allows it, as both MPPTs feed the DC bus, both the inverter and the battery charger take power from the bus, all these blocks have max power limits, but the bus doesn't.

So how much Voc you can use depends on your climate. If you have cold winters it will be less to allow for increased Voc at low temperature. If you're under the tropics, no problem. DEYE is a bit low on voltage, so it'll work best with lower voltage higher current panels, with high enough Impp to max out the MPPT input current.

So the reason why the inputs of inverters are not designed as a Buck-Boost (to be able to also  step down the voltage) but as a Boost converter (driven by the MPPT) is because in almost any cases it is not a problem and using a Buck-Boost is more expensive or less efficient?

Yes, it would be redundant, as the actual inverter circuit (DC to AC) already does the job of stepping down voltage

Thanks for your explanation!
